# How to handle multiple kafka topics with springboot app?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, confluent-platform

I’m implementing RestFul api using spring boot application. Based on the requester, I need to pick the topic and get the data from that topic.
Let say if I hit url requester1/data then I should get data from topic1 and if I hit the url requester2/data then I should get the data from topic2 and so on.

So how to handle these multiple topics in the spring boot app and get data from a particular topic when I get the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. you should inject a `ConsumerFactory<?, ?>` into your RESTFull service and use a `KafkaConsumer` API directly.

Any existing `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` architecture in the Spring Kafka is long-lived, event-driver implementation it can't be adjusted at runtime to perform consumption on demand. That's exactly for what `KafkaConsumer` exists.

Comment: It's an unusual use case, but Spring Boot auto configures a `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory`, based on boot properties. Use that to create a consumer, subscribe to the topic and `poll()` until no more records are retrieved.